# In R on Jupyter Notebook: “there is no package called ‘faraway’”

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook

I am using R on jupyter notebook

I am trying to learn some commands

I install the package as in

```
install.packages('faraway', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')
```

The outcome was

```
also installing the dependencies 'minqa', 'nloptr', 'RcppEigen', 'lme4'
Warning message in install.packages("faraway", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org"):
  "installation of package 'minqa' had non-zero exit status"
Warning message in install.packages("faraway", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org"):
  "installation of package 'nloptr' had non-zero exit status"
Warning message in install.packages("faraway", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org"):
  "installation of package 'RcppEigen' had non-zero exit status"
Warning message in install.packages("faraway", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org"):
  "installation of package 'lme4' had non-zero exit status"
Warning message in install.packages("faraway", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org"):
  "installation of package 'faraway' had non-zero exit status"
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library' Making 'packages.html' ... done
```

In the terminal I got that

```
ERROR: dependency ‘lme4’ is not available for package ‘faraway’
* removing ‘/anaconda3/lib/R/library/faraway’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/sk/ls5hgt056k72k2yxpm01jct00000gn/T/RtmpZijWPV/downloaded_packages’
[I 07:36:55.974 LabApp] Saving file at /4/Untitled1.ipynb
[E 07:36:55.984 LabApp] Notebook JSON is invalid: Additional properties are not allowed ('execution_count' was unexpected)

    Failed validating 'additionalProperties' in error:

    On instance['cells'][7]['outputs'][0]:
    {'ename': 'ERROR',
     'evalue': 'Error in library("minqa"): there is no package called ‘minqa’\n',
     'execution_count': 3,
     'output_type': 'error',
     'traceback': ['Error in library("minqa"): there is no package called '
                   '‘minqa’\n'
                   'Tr...',
                   '1. library("minqa")',
                   '2. stop(txt, domain = NA)']}
```

then afterwards

```
require('faraway')
```

The outcome was

> Loading required package: faraway Warning message in library(package,
>   lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE, :
>   “there is no package called ‘faraway’”

also if I command

```
library('faraway')
```

> Error in library("faraway"): there is no package called ‘faraway’
>   Traceback:

Is there any advice on this? Thank you

Comment: We cannot help unless you include the rest of the console text after you ran `install.packages`. I've never seen it *not* install the package without at least some kind of error/warning, even if vague and/or unintuitive.

Comment: @r2evans Thank you for trying to provide some help, but what do you mean exactly? How can I provide you with the "rest of the console text' I am using jupyter notebook.

Comment: You know, I don't really know, since I don't use jupyter notebooks all that often. But what has been provided is completely insufficient to help, as what you are missing is what will help us solve the problem. Perhaps in the interim you can find out how to get the R console messages/warnings/errors underneath a notebook? (I'm not being snarky, I really don't know, but once you know that the rest may fall into place.)

Comment: I added what has been said in the console, did that help?

Comment: You can see from the warning messages that `faraway` (and other packages) were not installed successfully. I'd be surprised if that were the complete warning message; there should be additional text which indicates what the issue was with installation.

Comment: It clearly demonstrates that you are having large problems installing packages. (One would think that a "non-zero exit status" would trigger an error, not a warning ...) So there must be more somewhere to those messages. Typically there's a link-loader message or a "headers not found" message or something similar. Do you have control over the underlying host OS? If so, what is it? Do you have a compiler available, either Rtools (windows) or clang/g++ (everything else)?

Comment: @r2evans this was the only warning messages I received. I am using a mac . I had the same issue with the package 'dplyr' but then after installing the package it worked (I got exactly the same result as in the package 'faraway') some how this work but faraway did not.

Comment: Can you run R by itself (not in jupyter) and try installing `faraway` there? If it works, I think it'll be available from within jupyter. If not, you'll have more information.

Comment: The error message specifically states that package 'lme4' isn't installed - I think because 'minqa' isn't isntalled. They should have been installed as dependencies. Usually when an R package installation fails, in my experience it's because the package or it's dependendt pacakge(s) have non-R dependencies (i.e. there's some software you need to download install on your workstation directly).

Answer (score 1):

Your first line of code worked for me

```
install.packages('faraway', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:
conda install -c conda-forge r-faraway